# How to get label text and selected value from checked radio button?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get  text and selected value from checked radio button and put it into variable. Trying to get something like "Is published" or if is other radio checked to be like "Is not In Review". This needs to be plain javascript - no jquery or any other framework.

```
    <form>
      <div class="filter-option">
        <input type="radio" id="status" name="status" checked="checked"/>
        <label for="status">Is</label>
        <div class="searchFilter">
          <select class="selectpicker" title="" data-size="false" multiple 
          data-live-search="true">
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="published">Published</option>
          <option value="draft">Draft</option>
          <option value="in-review">In Review</option>
          <option value="deleted">Deleted</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-option">
      <input type="radio" id="is_not" name="status"/>
      <label for="is_not">Is not</label>
      <div class="searchFilter">
        <select class="selectpicker" title="" data-size="false" multiple data- 
        live-search="true">
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="published">Published</option>
          <option value="draft">Draft</option>
          <option value="in-review">In Review</option>
          <option value="deleted">Deleted</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="filter-option">
        <input type="radio" id="contain" name="author"/>
        <label for="contain">Contain</label>
        <div class="searchFilter">
          <input type="text" class="simpleSearch">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: What have you done to solve this problem? We're here to *help* you solve and understand your problems, not to provide free code.

Answer (score 1):

You give the select element an id, then use `document.getElementById(id).value`.
This should return the value of the selected option, which you can then use any way you want.
Using `.text` instead gives you the text shown to the user in the list (in this example they are the same).

Comment: by the way, I just noticed the question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript